# Method Overloading - Java

Tags: java, java-8

**Actual Question:** **If it calls (1) then how can I make it so that it calls (2) ?**

I have following methods signature

```
public void myMethod(String myStr, MyClass myClass) {...} // (1)

public void myMethod(Object... objects) {...} // (2)
```

Somewhere I make a call like

`myMethod(new String("name"), new MyClass());`

Which overloaded method will be called ? If it calls **(1)** then how can I make it so that it calls **(2)** ?

Comment: why don't you try it and see the results?

Comment: I have to write long code to test this. That's why !\

Comment: @Junaid huh... It requires 3 lines of code to test it...

Comment: So you expect us to do that for u, anyways, I blame the folks who are answering the question

Comment: Why would you want to call the second method if the parameters types matches exactly the first one ?

Comment: If you have such issues, you should reconsider the method signatures to remove any ambiguity. Your methods don't do the same things when given the same parameters so they should get a different name that reflects what they actually do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will call (1) because the method resolution algorithm gives priority to methods that do not use varargs.

To force it to use (2) you can pass an array or cast the first parameter to `Object`:

```
myMethod(new Object[] { "name", new MyClass() });
//or
myMethod((Object) "name", new MyClass());
```

Comment: I was looking for `myMethod(new Object[] { "name", new MyClass() });`. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In Java, it takes the method which is most specific. This is according to Java [JLS 15.12.2.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5).

This doc says:

> If more than one member method is both accessible and applicable to a method invocation, it is necessary to choose one to provide the descriptor for the run-time method dispatch. The Java programming language uses the rule that the most specific method is chosen.

If you need to invoke the generic method instead, I think you need to cast each of the parameters to generic type `Object` as:

```
myMethod((Object) "hello", (Object) new MyClass());
```

Or, use as

```
myMethod(new Object[]{"name", new MyClass()});
```

Answer (score 0):

I will put this simply. Given that you are calling the constructor and passing a String and a MyClass object, it will obviously call the overloaded method which takes two arguments which are a String as arg 1 and a MyClass object as arg 2.